How do you secure joist to rim joist that rests on double 2x4 top plate
I have a small room that is 10x10 with double 2x4 top-plate around the entire perimeter. I am going to install rim-joists around the perimeter to ensure it is square before installing the 2x10 floor joists 16" on center through it. Because I don't have access to the outside of the rim joists I was going to use Simpson L70Z Reinforcing angles in the corners and Simpson LUS210Z joist hangers for the joists in the middle. My only issue is that the joist hangers will bring the joists slightly proud of the rim joist since they will be resting on the top plate.
Should I use an osc tool and cut a 2" deep, 1.5" wide, 2mm down notch in the top plate for the joist hanger to sit in so that the joist will be flush with the rim joist or can I simply rest the joist on the 2" of available top plate and toenail it into the rim joist?
I'm not sure which method would be best from a structural standpoint I am just trying learn.

Is it a top plate on top of a wall, or a sill plate on top of a foundation?  2x4s sound like a wall.  And why do you not have access to the outside?

@crip659 because the surrounding rooms/exterior walls are vaulted/higher. I am converting awkwardly high/pointy/vaulted ceilings above an entire portion of our home into a usable storage room.

That does not make any sense. perhaps you are using one of the technical terms in a novel way. draw a picture of what you have and what you plan to add.

What does not make sense?

I think joists must fit/lay on at least 1.5 inches on support.  you must check this measurement yourself, if I am mistaken.  2x4s are 3.5 inches long by 1.5 inches wide, so might have enough for the joists and rim.

@crip659 i've read the same thing in similar posts. After my rim-joist I'd be left with 2" so you are correct. I'm just unsure of correct connection methods or if I could and how to toe-nail a joist into a rim-joist.

For a rim joist, might just go with angle brackets, but depends on local inspector.  Toe-nails/screws are near edges and need to careful with splitting wood.  Pilot holes will help.

Joists sitting on a top plate do not need hangers, they are supported by the wall below. You can toenail the joists to the rim joist from the inside.

Thank you for the concise reply/answer. What size screws and how many should I use on each side? I cannot find anything specific.
